# How to write guitar tremolo with Sibelius software?

Tags: guitar, software, tremolo, sibelius

I'm trying to create the music sheet of "Recuerdos de La Alhambra" with Sibelius music notation software.
How to create tremolos in Sibelius?

Answer (score 2):

I Use **Sibelius G7**.

Tremolos are located on third pane of Keypad.

Press CTRL+ALT+K (or menu Windows->Keypad) to display Keypad window,
and then "+" key on numeric keyboard (or just use Your mouse to click) to navigate to third pane.

You have options from 2 up to 32 tremolos.

[image: Examples of tremolos in Sibelius G7]

Examples of tremolos in Sibelius G7

Comment: This is also correct on Sibelius 6, assuming OP is indeed looking for this particular notational symbol.